# Strong Parameters with complex parameters and empty arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I've been having trouble with Rails 4 and the usage of Strong Parameters and I can't seem to find the answer in the Rails guides or on the Strong Parameters github page.

Let's say I have an object coming into my app through a HTTP POST request that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "My Object",
  "children": {
    "child_1": [1,2,3],
    "child_2": []
  }
}
```

And I have permitted parameters as so:

```
params.permit(:name, {children: [{child_1: []}, {child_2: []}]});
```

Now, `child_1` is allowed to pass through fine, but `child_2` is stripped out as being Unpermitted.  How do I allow an empty array to pass through to the model?

Also, what if I wanted to pass child_1:

```
{
  "name": "My Object",
  "children": {
    "child_1": 1,
    "child_2": []
  }
}
```

Now, instead of passing `child_1` as an array, I would like to also allow a single integer, this way user can either pass a single ID or an array of IDs.

Is this possible with Strong Parameters and if so, what would the permit statement look like?

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error while doing this??

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors.  Should I be?

Comment: You could try `params.require(:xyz).permit(:name, {children: { child_1: [], child_2: [] }})`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks. Yes, I've tried that and it will not allow an empty array or a single integer/string to come through.  It does however allow an array of scalars, which the docs state.